# Capturing bash output from NodeJS

Tags: bash, node.js

Is it possible to start and continue to capture output from a certain bash process with node? For example: say I was run `tail /some/file`, how can I keep listening to every new line printed and act on the output?

Comment: Well, you'd need to attach to the standard-output from the process...not sure if you can do that from node.js.

Comment: @Bobby Yes you can, very easily as a matter of fact. See the `child_process` module. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness, I've added this answer as well.

You can use `child_process.spawn` to spawn a process and monitor it's output. However, for a command like tail, cat, etc that don't run long or continuously you can just use [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and it will capture the entire output for `stdout` and `stderr` and give it to you all at once.

```
var cp = require("child_process");

cp.exec("tail /some/file", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    // If an error occurred, err will contain that error object
    // The output for the command itself is held in stdout and stderr vars
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    tail  = spawn('tail', ['-f', '/tmp/somefile']);
tail.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

child_process module is [well documented](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: You can also run [`exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and it'll gather the entire output of `stdout` and `stderr` for you. For an instance like `tail` that'll work out fine. (If you have a continously running script, monitoring the output streams is a better option)

Comment: Yep my script is a continous one, for example `tail` or Google App Engine's `dev_appserver.py`. I'll test this and get back to you.